# Definite article with plural nouns

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles

Are there cases where the definite article is used with a plural noun, or is it a rule that the definite article is never used with the plural of a word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definite article can be used with a plural noun just as it can with a singular noun.

> **The** boys are here.

Answer (score 6):

Definite article can definitely be used with plural nouns. The restriction is limited to indefinite articles only.